# Authentication error when sending email from workflow but list alerts email work fine

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, workflow

I have a list. When a user enables alert on this list then he/she is able to receive email from SharePoint when someone adds a new item or change item.

But emails sent by SharePoint workflow (OOB Publishing workflow) workflow are not being sent. Error is:

> Error 530 5.7.1 Client was not authenticated

Why emails are not being sent by workflows?